# How to show information of a query table on the side of the page?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm outputting a table from a query:

```
<table >
      <thead><th >Name</th><th >Department</th></thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfoutput query="GetDept"  >
    <tr>
        <td >#dept_name# </td>  
        <td >#deptphone_name#</td>      
    <!---   <td >#deptphone_num#</div></td>  --->   
    <!---   <td >#deptphone_room#</div></td>  --->   
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

How can I get it that when i click on the #dept_name# i will be able to get 
more information of that department on the side of the page?

For example when I click on the dept_name on the side of the page(table)
I will get more information of the query , deptphone_num and deptphone_room.

Answer (score 0):

Showing and hiding content is a combination of ColdFusion and javascript. The solution below requires jQuery

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>      
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
    </tr>    
</thead>
<tbody>
<cfoutput query="GetDept"  >
<tr>
    <td>#dept_name# </td>  
    <td><a href="javascript:$(##deptphone#currentrow#).toggle();$(##deptroom#currentrow#).toggle();">#deptphone_name#</a></td>      
    <td><span style="display : none;" id="deptphone#currentrow#>#deptphone_num#</span></td>   
    <td><span style="display : none;" id="deptroom#currentrow# >#deptphone_room#</span></td>   
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For more information on jQuery toggle()

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: with something like this would i be able to show information of the query even if i dont show it on the table , so i can show it on the side

Comment: Side of the page is different from the side of the table. You may want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: i have edit the question , since that what i actually meant to ask , on the side of the page